# How to detect end of line character in a textbox string (VB6)

Tags: string, vb6, character, line, letter

i have a problem with VisualBasic6 .

i have 3 Textbox and 2 Command Button .

i want to detect VbCrLf when checking first textbox , letter by letter then write in another in second textbox: 101
and another function check the second textbox , if found 101 then make a new line (vbcrlf) in the third textbox.

in a Command  :

```
For i = 1 to len(text1.text)
   if Mid(txtD.Text, i, 1) = vbcrlf then
      text2.text = 101
   endif
next
```

in Command2 :

```
if text2.text = 101 then
  text3.text = text3.text & vbcrlf
endif
```

but when i check for Vbcrlf , it seem that character is not a newline-character and text2.text doesn't fill `101`

Also i tried VbNewLine but there is same problem !

Thank You my friends !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to check exactly what the new line delimiter is. I have seen vbcr,  vblf, & vbcrlf. VbNewLine is the same as vbcrlf.

Also, even if you do have vbcrlf in your string, your test will still fail. vbcrlf is **TWO** characters. You're testing just one character at a time.

A better test would the InStr() function. This is a quick test to see if a smaller string is anywhere in the larger one. So, your test would look like this:

```
If InStr(txtD.Text, vbcr) or InStr(txtD.Text, vblf) then
  text2.text = 101
End If
```

Comment: `vbNewLine` is equal to `vbCrLf` on a Windows machine but not identical at all since the compiler optimizes for vbNewLine, making it preferable almost all of the time.  But I agree that it makes no sense to test for String equality between a 1 char value and a 2 char value.

Comment: @Bob77, I was unfamiliar with this, so I Googled it for more details. Thanks.